# Echad Vachamishim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred fifty-one?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jews sinned during the days of the *shof'tim* for 151 years. Source: parenthetical remark printed in *Rashi* to *Y'chezkel* 4:5. To fit the tune, 151 were the sin-years of the judges, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

On 8 Adar the Jews of Barbados were granted permission to take an oath on the Old Testament, 1674. This was a first for the New World. **151 years later**, also on 8 Adar, Jews of Maryland were allowed to take a non-Christian oath. A declaration of belief in Reward and Punishment in the World to Come was part of their oath.

[Adar (Orthodox Union)](http://www.ou.org/about/judaism/bhyom/hebrew/adar.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Yaakov Avinu finished working for Rachel 7 years after he married her. He was 84 when he got married + 7 = 91

Yitzchak was 60 years older than Yaakov - so Yitchok was 151 when yaakov finished working for Rachel.

Answer (score 1):

According to various Kabbalistic sources going back to the Arizal, one who becomes angry should fast 151 fasts in atonement (this being the gematria of כעס plus one for the overall word (כולל)). This number is also associated with the root קנא, "to be jealous," as in the description of Pinchas' zealousness for G-d's honor during the affair at Shittim.

Answer (score -1):

ותרא את התבה בתוך **הסוף = 151**